# How to change Server.Transfer code to PHP redirect code with member_id

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net

I have a code in VB that looks like this:

```
'Server.Transfer(txtUser.Text + "_page.aspx")
```

which is taking a forms authenticated user to their page. For example if John logs in, it will take him to john_page.aspx.

How will I be able to integrate this in a PHP login script?
I'm trying something like:

```
header("location: $member . _page.php");
```

but I don't think I'm doing this correctly.  I'm not sure if this is just the wrong syntax or if I'm going about it the wrong way.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$page = "_page.php";
header("Location: http://example.com/".$page);
exit();
```

You need to use the full URL if you want to redirect using header().

Comment: So if I wanted to show a specific page for each user I could do something like this? $user = "member_id"; $page = "_page.php"; header("Location: http://example.com/".$user.$page); exit(); to show something like http://example.com/john_page.php

Comment: Yes you could to that (remove that semicolon before $user).